# How do you pick neutral fonts for smartphone?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, fonts, smartphone

When you should make apps for smartphone on multi-platform - iOS, Android, WP7, ... -,
how do you make a decision what fonts will be used, and how to deploy it?

I thought using just embed truetype fonts or neutral font things, like in following article : http://www.bluetrainmobile.com/blog/choosing-fonts-for-your-mobile-website, but I don't have an idea which way will be better one.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re making a native app, then I’d stick with the fonts native to the platform. Helvetica on iOS, etc. That’s what those users are familiar with.

Comment: Well, I assumed an app has same look and feel in various platforms. In this case, will it be a gold rule using native, default font like Helvetica of iOS?